# Using Jquery datatable jeditable without mandatory field URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jeditable

How can you use `jquery.datatable` and the `jeditable` plugin without a url. I just want edit functionality without saving to the server. This is what I've tried:

```
$('td', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable(function(value, settings) { 
    console.log(this);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(settings);
    return(value);}, { 
       type    : 'textarea',
       submit  : 'OK',
       callback: function( sValue, y ) {
           var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
       oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
     },
});
```

Comment: @Christopher Pfohl: As I understand your bounty comment, my [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j78pR/2/) is what you are looking for. Is there anything missing?

Comment: @Wolfram no, that's exactly it! Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I took the [Jeditable (or jEditable) example on datatables.net](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html) and modified it based on what Golden Bird provided in the question and what the [Jeditable docs](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) say on this topic. To test, you may edit any value in the grid, the sorting applies at once and everything else datatables-related works as well (e.g. searching for the new value).

- [Example using (implicit) `"type" : "textarea"`](http://jsfiddle.net/j78pR/)
- **[Example using `"type" : "select"`](http://jsfiddle.net/j78pR/2/)**

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('table').dataTable();

    var theCallback = function(v, s) {
        // Do something with the new value
        return v;
    };
    $(oTable).find('td').editable(theCallback, {
        "callback": function(sValue, y) {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
            oTable.fnUpdate(sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1]);
        },
        "data": "{'0':'0%', '.1':'10%', '.15': '15%', '.2': '20%', 'selected':'0'}",
        "type" : "select",
        "submit" : "OK",
        "style": {"height": "100%","width": "100%"}
    });
});
```

Comment: You just ended 48 hours of seaching the entire web. Thank you!