# jquery-datatable-jeditable showing edited value in browser but not saving in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jeditable, jquery-datatables-editor

I was follwing below post for jeditable plugin . [Using Jquery datatable jeditable without mandatory field URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874276/using-jquery-datatable-jeditable-without-mandatory-field-url). (I want user to edit the table and once its done , user can click on submit button and send it for processing.)
Everything works perfect ,data is getting edited and I can see the updated value in table but When I click on Sumbit button ,at server side I am getting old values.I don't know what am I missing Here. Moreover if I do "view-source" of html page I cant see the updated value , though I can see updated value in browser:-

```
  $(document).ready(function() { /* Init DataTables */
        var oTable = $('table').dataTable();

        /* Apply the jEditable handlers to the table */
        var theCallback = function(v, s) {
            console.debug("Element", this);
            console.debug("New value:", v);
            console.debug("Setting object:",s);
            return v;
        };
        $(oTable).find('td').editable(theCallback, {
            "callback": function(sValue, y) {
                console.log("jEditable callback is executed => updating dataTable");
                var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
          alert(sValue);


    }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I left the idea of updating table's data at client side. I followed awesome article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193068/Adding-data-management-CRUD-functionalities-to-the and used ServerSide approach.Now I am making ajax call to update table's data ,Ajax call will call UpdateDataServlet and update table's column's data and refresh table at client side. I had struggled at lot to find a solution to my problem. Hope this help someone.